# PHP using a variable from before it's defined

Tags: php, html, title

I have a file named `page.php` and it is something like this;

```
<? include "header.php"; ?>
<body>
...
</body>
<? include "header.php"; ?>
```

Between the `<body>` tags, I run a sql query and get a variable called as `$title`.
I want to show that variable as the html title of my page which is in the `header.php` .

How can I do this?

I simply tried what i said, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can't do it directly. About all you can do is use PHP to generate a piece of javascript that will then re-write the page's `<title>`. Though it might be easier to move the PHP that generates `$title` to before you set the page's title?

Comment: you can define the <title> inside the body, but its not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it before the `<body>` tags, save the results to a variable, and process this variable wherever you want (as a title and in the `<body>` tags).

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid mixing PHP code with your HTML. Run the SQL query before you include header.php, store the results in an variable, and store the title in a variable. For example:

```
<?php
// SQL code here, store the data in e.g. $data and title in $title
include "header.php";
?>
<body>

<?php
// output page using $data
?>

</body>
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
```

Then your header.php would include something like `<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>`